# How to fix sporadic drawable tinting?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable

I am using android support library and besides limited number of widgets that are tinted with color accentColor defined in theme I would like to tint some other drawables which I use across my app.
I do this via this code:

```
public class ActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void tintDrawable(int color, int drawableId) { 
        Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableId));
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    }

    protected void tintDrawables() {
        int colorPrimary = getColorFromAttributeId(this, R.attr.colorPrimary);
        tintDrawable(colorPrimary, R.drawable.drawable_1);
        tintDrawable(colorPrimary, R.drawable.drawable_2);
        tintDrawable(colorPrimary, R.drawable.drawable_3);
        tintDrawable(colorPrimary, R.drawable.drawable_4);
        tintDrawable(colorPrimary, R.drawable.drawable_5);
        tintDrawable(colorPrimary, R.drawable.drawable_6);
    }


    public static int getColorFromAttributeId(Context context, int resourceAttributeId) {
        int[] attributes = new int[] { resourceAttributeId }; 
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributes);     
        int color = typedArray.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        typedArray.recycle();
        return color;
    }

    protected void doSetPreferencedThemeOnCreateSetContentView(Bundle savedInstanceState, int layoutResourceId) {
        /* Catch 22: 
         * This order must be used otherwise an exception is thrown or theme is not applied.
         *  1. setTheme()
         *  1.b tintDrawables only after the theme is known we can get the color
         *  2. onCreate()
         *  3. setContentView()      *  
         *  4. setSupportActionBar() */
        // Apply theme. This must be done before super.onCreate()
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Custom_Theme);   // in real case theme is retrieved from preferences
        tintDrawables();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layoutResourceId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        doSetPreferencedThemeOnCreateSetContentView(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_test);
    }

}
```

It looks complicated but it is easy to understand. The problem is that my drawables are tinted "randomly". Some are, and some are not and retain the color as set in original png. To make matters worse if I leave the activity and come back, the result might be different. There could be more drawables tinted correctly or less. 
What I am guessing is that tinting is asynchronous and the layout gets created before tint is applied to all drawables. But this is just a guess.
This problem is annoying as my UI depends on correct tinting, White icons on white background are not much of use. Neither are black on black.
How to enforce correct tinting of drawables?

Comment: Any info on this? Most probably it is another android bug.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but I ran in to the same problem. Calling mutate() on the drawable ensures that it will not share its state with any other drawable. From the docs:

"By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification"

In my case, this was causing random problems with the tinting.